# wordpress image upload programmatically to custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, image, upload

I am going to implement a plugin where it is possible to upload (two) images for anonymous-user (from the fronted). Thereby, thumbnail of the images should also be shown. Therefore, I created a custom post type with two custom (image-)fields.

Now I would like to implement the upload for the images. I already did some research and thereby, I found the wordpress function "wp_insert_attachment" to save files. But - how is it now possible to save the images to the custom fields (with thumbnail when uploading these images)?

Could anyone help me?

Thank you!